# How can I send and receive data from an external webpage?

Tags: php

I am building a PHP script that needs to use content loaded from an external webpage, but I don't know how to send/receive data.

The external webpage is http://packer.50x.eu/ .

Basically, I want to send a script (which is manually done in the first form) and receive the output (from the second form).

I want to learn how to do it because it can surely be an useful thing in the future, but I have no clue where to start.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: CURL() would be a start, although you example is a little off-putting, Obfuscator's are a joke

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in curl() docs then. Yeah, I need to use it just to have another minimum layer of protection from script kiddies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `curl` to receive data from external page. Look this example:

```
$url = "http://packer.50x.eu/";

$ch = curl_init($url);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // you can use some options for this request
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // or not to use them
// you can set many others options. read about them in manual
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data); // < -- here is received page data
```

[curl_setopt manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at file_get_contents($url) as it is very simple to use, simpler than CURL (more limited though), so your code could look like:

```
$url = "http://packer.50x.eu/";
$url_content=file_get_contents($url);
echo $url_content;
```

Look at the documentation as you could use offset and other tricks.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I needed something a little bit more.